# ASP.Net Custom controls vs. user controls: Are these two the same

Tags: asp.net, user-controls

If they are different, under what circumstances should we decide to use either approach?

Also, what is the advantage of ascx over aspx?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

user controls are a form of custom control, that gives you a visual designer. They are ideal for use when you want a reusable control within the same web site. (It is possible to create and package user controls as seperate assemblies but that is beyond the scope of this question and I know has been asked on SO).

A custom control is typically used to refer to a Web Control, or a Composite Control which is specialized form of a web control. These controls have no designer and are usually implemented in seperate projects from your web allowing them to be reused accross many sites.

Now your second question, ASCX and ASPX are two different things. ASCX is the extension for a User Control, where as ASPX is an ASP.Net Page. You cannot use an ASCX by itself it must be placed onto an ASPX or Master page.

One way I like to use user controls is I have for example a very complex page which have 7 tabs, 5 of those have grids, of those grids three of them are identicle. Well what I can do is create a seperate user control for the content of the tabs, this now reduces the code I need down significantly (Since three grids are identicle except for the data).

Further more it allows multiple to work on various parts of the page, and it helps me keep everything straight since I am reducing the complexity of the page. You do not use User Controls instead of Pages, you use them in conjuction with a page.

## Edit

You do not use ascx over aspx. You use ascx to complement. For example on my site every page has the same footer, but I don't want every page to derive from a single master page. I can create my footer as an acsx control and put it in each of my master pages.

Another example, I have a form that lets a user enter three different date ranges. (And we have other forms). So I put the logic to enable a calender button, and a text box that when clicked on opens up the calender, in a user control. I can then reuse that user control in all my aspx pages.

Comment: then what is the advantage by using ascx over aspx

Answer (score 5):

**Custom controls** are control build entirely in code. The pro is that you can put them in libreries, add an icon to the toolbox and other fine control.

**User controls** are more easy to do, and in general is a way to encapsulate things to simplify other pages or when you need to use the same markup in several pages.

The advantage of controls over regular aspx pages is that you only need to do some part of the markup (not the whole page)

Answer (score 3):

**User Controls/Composite controls**

User controls that are made up of other ASP.Net or custom controls. They are usually quite straight forward and can be created quite quickly. They Are generally not shared across projects however there are some [tricks](http://webproject.scottgu.com/CSharp/UserControls/Usercontrols.aspx) that can allow you to do this.

**Custom controls**

Custom controls are controls that you implement the UI by creating everything from the HTML output to design time support. Custom controls take much longer to make. You must use either Web.UI.Control or inherit from a sub control (Textbox for example). Custom controls are compiled to binary format to allow them to be distributed more easily. Since they are compiled they can be referenced from the toolbox in visual studio.

There are 2 main advantages to using a control **in** an aspx page. Encapsulation of logic and reuseability.

Comment: then what is the advantage of ascx over aspx then

Comment: To be clear you cannot replace a aspx page with a usercontrol.